# Searching Objects on SonicWALL (NSA 2600, SonicOS 6.1)

Tags: firewall, sonicwall

Ok, this may sound like a dumb question, but does the SonicOS web interface not have a search option for object definitions?

One of my clients recently decided to replace their Astaro Security Gateways with SonicWALL firewalls.  These sit in front of a small data center full of servers and we have several hundred custom service and address definitions that need to be ported.

The SonicOS interface provides a basic list for service and address definitions but no search option to be found.  To make it worse, there is no option to list them all on one page (they're paginated 50 at a time) so I can't use the text search on the web browser either.  The Astaro units have a nice search option on their definitions so perhaps I just got spoiled by their software.

Am I missing something or is there some way to search for an object without paging through the list and finding an entry manually?

Comment: And they aren't alphabetical either which makes it that much more painful.

Comment: I found that if I selected the filter to only show custom objects and then sort by name I can get an alphabetical list, but still a pain to have to page through a few thousand objects 50 at a time to find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly in the GUI, but there are two alternatives that might work.

1. A TSR.  If you go to System->Diagnostics and download a Technical Support report, you'll get a dump of settings in plain text.  This can searched easily.
2. The CLI.  Not sure how easy it is to search, but the newer models have a CLI that you can access via ssh if enabled.  The address objects can be viewed here.  For more info check out the [KB article](https://www.fuzeqna.com/sonicwallkb/ext/kb6180-cli-modelproseries1260-modelproseries2040-modelproseries3060-modelproseries4060-modelproseries4100).